# How to don't kill server and refresh over 2000 images through simplexml class and GD?

Tags: php, mysql, cron, simplexml, gd

That's quite complicated, but I'll try to describe my problem as clear as I can. So I have PHP application which is addon for Last.fm (I guess most of you know this site and know how it works). This app uses Lastfm's XML files. My script counts which artist was most played artist from last month, so when you use it, for example, today (29 September), it will generate png file with artist of August (I mean artist name and his photo). User of this app had BBCode to paste it into his profile, e.g.: `scriptname.php?user=example`.

But problem begins when it comes to new month. When my app wasn't very popular, I just wrote down generated file on my server and when new month came and user visited his profile (which means that he forced my app to start), script generated another one and everything was clear. But now I have about ~2000 users and this method would kill my server, actually already killed it for a while (on 1 September, of course...). Now I don't know what to do, of course I was forced to turn off this service. I was thinking about cronjob or sth, but my hosting doesn't support SSH and, for now, I have no money to buy new server. Do you have any ideas how to regenerate this huge amount of images every month WITHOUT cron? Thanks a lot for any tips and sorry for my poor English.

Additional info (not sure if useful or not): to save some server transfer (80 GB per month limit) I am saving in database some data about each user: nickname on last.fm, last month number, fav artist from last month and link to generated image from imageshack, on each visit script relocates to imageshack.

Comment: Every hosting should support cronjob. What did you admin said when you asked him that you wish to have cronjob?

Comment: you need to do incremental updates, instead of trying to do everything at once.

Comment: and, like glavic said, you should be able to schedule a cronjob - this doesn't have anything to do with SSH. if you've got cpanel, there should be an option there to do this. about bandwidth, JPGs are potentially smaller than PNGs too!

Comment: @glavić: he just said that it's impossible for my hosting plan, I have virtual host and cronjob works only on dedicated servers... That's stupid and probably I'll be forced to buy new server elsewhere.

Comment: @danp: what do you mean? Probably that's my fold, but in fact I have no control under those updates. When someone visits profile with my app on it and current month is different with the one in database, update of his image is automatic. And I have DirectAdmin and there is no such option, actually there is, but greyed out and unclickable

Comment: Well, you need to rework the script so that it's pulling a cached version of the image, instead of calculating it every time it's called. Then you can do incremental updates with some daily cronjob.

Comment: every time it's called (and not the current month)*

Answer (score 0):

Its probably me getting this wrong though; But you don’t really need cronjobs if you have 2000 users a day and when you just create one new image a month. From what I got you just need to cache these images instead of relocate them to imageshack… or well, relocate them but keep the url on the database or somewhere else... just keep it ;) and use that one of course!